# Search array by values and return keys

Tags: php, arrays, search, key

I have values passed *c* and *3* from `$_GET` variable, which I want to look up in an array as values and retrieve their keys. How can I search through the array to return accurate keys?

The code below

```
<?php

$array1 = array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'c', 2 => 'c');
$array2 = array(0 => '3', 1 => '2', 2 => '3');

$key1 = array_search('c', $array1);
$key2 = array_search('3', $array2);

?>
```

returns

```
$key1 = 1;
$key2 = 0;
```

though I am expecting

```
$key1 = 2;
$key2 = 2;
```

Comment: It is an accurate result because these keys do have the values you were searching for. Is your criterion that you want to find the *last* key that has that value? Isn't there a better way to do whatever you want to do with this?

Comment: What's inaccurate about that?

Comment: I want those key from $array1 and $array2 are matches together, cause both arrays are linked to perform sql process. It must match if passes value is 'c' and '3', the keys for both return must be $key1 = 2 and $key2 = 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == 'c' && $array2[$key] == '3') {
        echo "The key you are looking for is $key";
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure there's a saner way to do whatever you're trying to do though.

Answer (score 3):

The function returned exactly as it should have. The first occurrence of value 'c' exists at index 1 in $array1 and the value '3' has its first occurrence at index 0 in $array2

This behavior is documented in [the php docs on array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and it even supplies you with an alternative if you don't like it:

> If needle is found in haystack more than once, the first matching key
>   is returned. To return the keys for all matching values, use
>   array_keys() with the optional search_value parameter instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the last key that has that value, you could reverse your array first.

```
$array1 = array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'c', 2 => 'c');
$array2 = array(0 => '3', 1 => '2', 2 => '3');

$key1 = array_search('c', $array1);
$key2 = array_search('3', $array2);

var_dump($key1,$key2); //output: int(1) int(0)


$key1 = array_search('c', array_reverse($array1, true));
$key2 = array_search('3', array_reverse($array2, true));

var_dump($key1,$key2); //output: int(2) int(2)
```

Comment: Not find the last key but find the values key that had passed from previous input, the values could be 'c' and '2' where these keys were returned correct due to the keys is first matching.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
<?php
// for specificly 2 arrays
function search_matching($match1, $match2, array $array1, array $array2) {
    foreach($array1 as $key1 => $value1) {
        // we may want to add $strict = false argument to distinguish between == and === match
        // see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php
        if($value1 == $match1 and isset($array2[$key1]) and $array2[$key1] == $match2) {
            return $key1;
        }
    }

    return null;
}


// unlimited
function search_matching(array($matches), array $array/*, ...*/) {
    if( count($matches) != func_num_args() - 1)
         throw new \Exception("Number of values to match must be the same as the number of supplied arrays");

    $arrays = func_get_args();
    array_shift($arrays);  // remove $matches
    $array = array_unshift($arrays); // array to be iterated

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
         if($value == $matches[0]) {
               $matches = true;

               foreach($arrays as $keyA => $valueA) {
                    if(! isset($arrays[$key] or $valueA != $matches[$keyA+1]) {
                        $matches = false;
                        break;
                    }                  
               }

               if($matches)
                   return $key;
         }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The functions are created with numerical keys in mind.

They could be made cleaner by offloading some functionality to other function, but I wanted to keep it concise and together for the sake of easily seeing how it works